# Space needed for a little more than basic Ubuntu installation

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, eclipse

I will want my basic dual boot Ubuntu installation alongside Windows to have the following:

1. JDK 7.0
2. Android Eclipse IDE
3. Some basic video playing programs (like VLC)
4. Shell utilities (I'm not sure, but I believe some of the utilities need to be downloaded)

Does 30GB space allocated to Ubuntu in my Windows laptop sound reasonable to achieve this Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 0):

30 GB is quite resonable it takes 4gb to install ubuntu and 4gb as swap area and rest are all your space you can install anything in it